# Placing id on input and select tags inside td depending on query result looping

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

asigning id for each input tag and select tag in tr depending on query result

I tried a code like this putting an id inside the input tag and select tag

```
        <table id="myTable">
          <thead>
               <th>Progress</th>
               <th>Amount</th>
               <th>Action</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php $qry = "SELECT * FROM trade";
                  foreach($conn->query($qry) as $data){
            ?>
            <form action="update.php" method="post">
            <tr>
               <td><select name="progress" id="select_progress" onclick="changeSetting()">
                       <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
                       <option value="Full">Full</option>
                   </select></td>
               <td><input type="number" name="amount" id="amount"></td>
               <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
               <input type="hidden" name="tradeid" value="<?php echo $data['tradeID'];?>">
            </tr>
            </form>
            <?php }?>
          </tbody>
         </table>
```

Now i coded the javascript like this:

```
        function changeSetting(){
             var selectValue = document.getElementById("select_progress").value;
             var amountValue = document.getElementById("amount");
             if(selectValue.value === "Partial"){
                   amountValue.required = true;
             }else if(selectValue.value === "Full"){
                   amountValue.required = false;
             }
        }
```

The first row seems to be doing fine, but the second row doesn't apply the javascript i wrote. Any suggestion on how to approach this would be welcome. I know, that an id should be unique for each element but if i have about 50 results in my query i dont know how to place id's on each input and select tag inside my table. Any suggestions or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: your rule is only applied on one set since you're bound on using `id`s, remake your rule to support via `class`es so that the same rule applies to all sets

Comment: @ghost yeah well im still new to PHP and javascripting, so i don't know how to structure it yet on looping based on mysql query, i did find some solutions on the class names with querySelector but it wasn't the answer i was searching,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your elements have the same `id` value, so when you try to `getElementById` it always returns the first one. One way to work around this is to add the `tradeID` value to each element's `id` value to distinguish them. For example:

```
<td><select name="progress" id="select_progress<?php echo $data['tradeID'];?>" onchange="changeSetting(<?php echo $data['tradeID'];?>)">
      <option value="Partial">Partial</option>
      <option value="Full">Full</option>
    </select></td>
 <td><input type="number" name="amount" id="amount<?php echo $data['tradeID'];?>"></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="update" value="Update"></td>
```

Then you would modify your JS as so:

```
function changeSetting(id){
  var selectValue = document.getElementById("select_progress" + id).value;
  var amountValue = document.getElementById("amount" + id);
  if(selectValue === "Partial"){
    amountValue.required = true;
  }else if(selectValue === "Full"){
     amountValue.required = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: oh didn't know that an id can include an echo from query, thanks a lot

Comment: tried out your suggestion on my post earlier, and it works great, thumbs up vote for this, i did erase out the .value inside the condition statement on the javascript since it is already pointed out in the getElement, but still this is a great help for me

Comment: yep this answer did great, sorry forgot to mark it, i'll do it now, thanks for the help

Comment: @justin no problem at all. I appreciate it.